# How to set Fortigate 60 as gateway

Tags: firewall, gateway, fortigate

I need to use Fortigate 60 as gateway. I just switched to NAT mode.

Gateway IP from ISP: XXX.255.136.41 - 255.255.255/48
Real IP from ISP - WAN2 IP: XXX.255.136.45
Internal IP : 192.168.35.1

I can ping those IP adresses from local & internet. However I cannot use 192.168.35.1 as gateway on my Windows 7.

I've added ALL ALLOW ANYTIME ANYWHERE firewall policy.
I've added 0.0.0.0 / 0.0.0.0 internal > XXX.255.136.41 static route as trial.
I've added 0.0.0.0 / 0.0.0.0 WAN2 > XXX.255.136.41 static route as trial.

Now I can't ping 8.8.8.8.

What are the correct settings to make Fortigate a gateway?

Answer (score 2):

**1-) Router:** 
Use  0.0.0.0 / 0.0.0.0 WAN2 > XXX.255.136.41 static route

**2-) Firewall:** 
At Firewall > Policy > edit related ACCEPT policy; choose [Enable NAT] instead of the default [No NAT].